# Get foreign key value with the url parameter

Tags: django

I am new in Django, and I have the next problem. I got a Foreign Key and I want to set the value for the foreign key with the url parameter.

For example:

In urls.py

```
(r'^cyc/presupuesto/nuevo/(?P<pk>/d+)/$', views.clientes_presupuesto_crear.as_view(model=Presupuesto, success_url="/crm/ok/"))
```

In clientes/models.py

```
class Presupuesto(models.Model):
    ESTADO_CHOICES = (('P', 'En Proceso'),('A', 'Aceptado'),('R', 'Rechazado'))
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cuenta,blank=True, null=True)
```

I want that when i enter to the mysite.com/cyc/presupuesto/nuevo/883
The value set in the foreign key will be 883.

Somebody has an idea?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: (r'^cyc/presupuesto/nuevo/(?P<cliente_id>/d+)/$', views.clientes_presupuesto_crear.as_view(model=Presupuesto, success_url="/crm/ok/"))   And also you should change the views according to your needs

Comment: So, in my views I got this:
    class clientes_presupuesto_crear(CreateView):
        model = Presupuesto
        form_class = forms.amPresupuestoForm
        template_name = 'clientes/presupuesto/nuevo.html'
        post_save_redirect = '/crm/ok/'
        login_required = True
        def get_succes_url(self):
            return reverse('presupuesto-lista')
There can I change so, I could get the cliente_id???

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using a generic Detail view.

the `pk` passed in the url will be passed to the generic view model. so...

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import Presupuesto, Cuenta


class CuentaDetail(DetailView):

    model = Cuenta
    template_name = 'cuenta/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(CuentaDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Get Presupuesto object and pass it to context
        context['obj_presupuestos'] = self.get_object().presupuesto_set.all()
        return context
```

This will fill your context passed to the template with all the `Presupuesto` objects referring to the `Cuenta` object specified in the URL.